# Rust generic parameter matching

Tags: rust

The problem arises when implementing From trait.
I understand the problem is that generic type T collides with RangeFull.

```rust
impl<T: Ord + 'static> From<RangeFull> for X<T> { ... }
impl<T: Ord + 'static> From<T> for X<T> { ... }
```

I was expecting the matching process as the following (like C++ template)

1. Check input type is RangeFull if yes, matched, otherwise go 2
2. match the most generic T

Comment: But it doesn't work like C++. Conflicting implementations are not allowed. You're looking for _specialization_, but it is not stable.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman :S Ok. <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844> It has been a long time...